# Conditional rendering inside map function ReactJs

Tags: html, reactjs

I know there's similar thread already but i'm a total newbie and i can't work it. I'm not able include conditional rendering after my map function, do i need some sortf of HTML-tag inbetween?

```
     const renderTableData = () => { 
    let id = 1;
    const activeButton = () => { 
    
    }
    return (
      <tr>
        {days.map((val) => (
            <td>
                 {timeSlot.map((n, i) => ( 
                    
                //     if(freeSlotsList.includes(id)){     THIS CODE SNIPPET
               //         return (<h1>Testing</h1>           DON'T WORK
              //          )}
                    
                 
              <button id={id++} className={activeButton}> {n} {id}</button> 
                 ))}
            </td>
        ))}
      </tr>
    );
  };
```

EDIT:

i can't seem to access my freeSlotsList, it looks like this

```
const [freeSlotsList, setFreeSlotsList] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
Axios.post('http://localhost:3001/api/get/week1/ex').then((response) => {
    setFreeSlotsList(response.data)

    
  })
}, [])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, You need to wrap your code into `{}` if you want to write js code. As `()` will simply return that as jsx.

```
const renderTableData = () => { 
let id = 1;
const activeButton = () => { 

}
return (
  <tr>
    {days.map((val) => (
        <td>
             {timeSlot.map((n, i) => {
                
                 if(freeSlotsList.includes(id)){     
                    return (<h1>Testing</h1>         
                    )}
                
             
          return <button id={id++} className={activeButton}> {n} {id}</button> 
             )}}
        </td>
    ))}
  </tr>
);
};
```

Comment: That's probably it! altough i can't display my button this way. Is there any way to circumvent that?

Comment: Probably there is some mismatch in closing brackets. And please wrap button in `( )`.

Comment: Ahh i found it, was )}} when it should've been })}.

Comment: I still can't access timeSlot  a useState([]) inside the function, do you have any clue as to why?

Comment: How `timeSlot` is being set? I guess you are referring wrong variable. Or add more description for that.

Comment: Oh i'm sorry my bad, i meant freeSlotsList.

Comment: Try to log your response. I am not seeing anything wrong with updating state .

Comment: I can't seem to access the return statement even though the id 1 should be included in freeSlotsList. could i write something like this,  if(freeSlotsList.map((n).includes(n.id))){     
                          return (<h1>Testing</h1>           
                          )}

Comment: What `freeSlotsList` holds?